# Java Exception Handling for Infinity

Tags: java, exception, infinity

I am trying to write a program to equate the value of any number to any power, and I'm suppose to implement exception handling for exponents less than zero which i successfully did and also exception handle for when the value is too large to output i.e. infinity.

heres my power class which contains the function Power :

```
public class power
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
public static double Power(double base, int exp) throws IllegalArgumentException
{  

    if(exp < 0){

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exponent cannot be less than zero");

    }
    else if(exp == 0){
        return 1;

    }


    else{
        return base * Power(base, exp-1);

    }
}

}
```

Heres the Test class :

```
public class powerTest
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  double [] base =  {2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0,  4.0 };
  int [] exponent = {10,   9,   -8, 6400, 53};

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     try {
        double result = power.Power(base[i], exponent[i]);
        System.out.println("result " + result);
     }   
     catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
  }
}
}
```

heres the output of the test :

```
result 1024.0
result 19683.0
Exponent cannot be less than zero
result Infinity
result 8.112963841460668E31
```

my question is how can i get "result infinity" to say something else through ArithmeticException handling something along the lines of "Floating point Overflow"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to throw an exception if the result is infinite? Do you want to know how to check if the result is infinite?

Comment: Throw exception when the result is infinite

Comment: Well clearly you know how to throw an exception. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can test for infinity/overflow with an if statement as well:

```
if( mfloat == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY ){

    // handle infinite case, throw exception, etc.
}
```

So in your situation, you would do something like this:

```
public static double 
Power(double base, int exp) throws IllegalArgumentException
{  

    if(exp < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exponent less than zero");
    }
    else if(exp == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{

        double returnValue = base * Power(base, exp-1);
        if(returnValue == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
            throw new ArithmeticException("Double overflowed");

        return returnValue;

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of mfloat I would need a variable that represents the value once the equation is executed and that's where I'm stuck

Comment: Thank you! That's all I asked for thanks for you're help,  accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

When you catch the exception, here

```
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

just do

```
System.out.println("Floating point Overflow")
```

as well(if you want to add more) or replace the first print with this statement

This way like you said, "you get result infinity" to say something else through ArithmeticException handling"

Comment: You're referring to the test class this doesn't tell me how to catch it through the power class,  I'm not using try and catch

Comment: in your test class, you are using try catch